# write to back page of part

Tags: koma-script, titlesec, double-sided, parts

I have defined (using koma-script), that chapters only start on the right side. The same applies to part pages. So far this is ok.

But now I want to insert a contents list (using `titletoc`) on the back side (left) of the part page. It shall list only the chapters, thus it will never span more than one page.

However by default the next opened page after `\part` is on the right side.

There are some hacks to solve this problem (found [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=20806))

```
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother
\part{Part Name}
This is the text I put on the back side of the part page
\makeatletter\@openrighttrue\makeatother
```

But I would like to have this configured in the preamble and have a clean code in the document. Is this possible somehow?

EDIT:
From the previous comments I could find out that `\renewcommand{\partheademptypage}{}` works until I reformat the part page using titlesec.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}   

\titleformat{\part}[frame]
  {\usekomafont{part}\Large\color{black}\centering}    % format
  % label: PART I
  {\enspace \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\partname}%           
     \centering \Huge~\thepart \enspace }%  
  % sep (from partnumber)
  {1.5\baselineskip}
  % (before chaptertitle and after)
  {\color{black}\filcenter}       

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\newcommand{\PartialToc}{%
\startcontents[part]
\section*{Contents}
\printcontents[part]{}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
}

\renewcommand{\partheademptypage}{}%

\part{Part Heading}
\PartialToc
\chapter{first}
\chapter{second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A clean solution is the usage of `KOMAoptions` instead of `makeatletter` `makeatother`. Please add a complete MWE.

Comment: The `scrbook` and `scrreprt` classes use the macro `\partheademptypage` for producing the blank page after the part page; so just redefining it to do nothing will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should show once again the importance of a minimal example. If you reformat the part page using `titlesec`, you're overriding for `\part` the commands used normally by `scrbook`, so redefining `\partheademptypage` won't do any good.

With `titlesec`, the control about the `\cleardoublepage` issued by `\part` is delivered to `\ttl@page@ii`, which is used by all "part" class sectioning commands, so it shouldn't be a problem for the rest of the document. Patching it so that the relevant `\if@openright` test is nullified is easy; but since `\if@openright` appears twice, we search for `\if@openright\null`, changing it into `\iffalse` that will ignore all tokens up to the matching `\fi`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}   

\titleformat{\part}[frame]
  {\usekomafont{part}\Large\color{black}\centering}    % format
  % label: PART I
  {\enspace \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\partname}%           
     \centering \Huge~\thepart \enspace }%  
  % sep (from partnumber)
  {1.5\baselineskip}
  % (before chaptertitle and after)
  {\color{black}\filcenter}

\newcommand{\PartialToc}{%
  \startcontents[part]
  \section*{Contents}
  \printcontents[part]{}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\ttl@page@ii{\if@openright\null}{\iffalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\part{Part Heading}
\PartialToc
\chapter{first}
\chapter{second}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to typeset something on the back side of a part that opens on the right side of a double page? Than `\renewcommand{\partheademptypage}{}` might help you:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\title{hello world}
\renewcommand{\partheademptypage}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\part{eins}
This is the text I put on the back side of the part page
\chapter{un}
\chapter{deux}
\chapter{trois}
\part{zweit}
This is some other text I put on the back side of the part page
\chapter{uno}
\chapter{due}
\chapter{tre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this work, however not with the MWE example that I added to the question.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: You are loading titlesec. Do you really need it?

Comment: I use it for redesigning the part and chapter headings. So yes I need it.